# Create images with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

How is it possible to create a loop that creates all the images and loads the hole page before it processing? I wanna to show the proccess when it creates the images like: 1 out of 100 images created, 2 out of 100 images created....

PHP code

```
// directory with all images (Source)
$profileimages = array_slice(scandir('Z:/'), 2); 

//Array that contains the filenames that should be created from SQL database
$profiles = Profiles();

$profileimages = array_map(function($e){
return pathinfo($e, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}, $profileimages);


$results = array_intersect($profileimages, $profiles);
$persons = implode(', ', $results);
```

Javascript

```
var list = ['<?php echo $persons; ?>'];
var arrayLength = list.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

// add-picture.php creates images to a destination directory
var myData = 'filename=' + list[i];
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "add-picture.php",
        data:myData,
        success:function(response){
            $("#list").html(i);

        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
</script>

<div id="list"></div>
```

It just need loop the array and visit the php page for every picture

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `$.each` function in jQuery to iterate over person, here is a stub of how it might look.

```
var persons = ['personA', 'personB', 'personC', 'personD'];
var $container = $("#list");
var numPersons = persons.length;

$(persons).each(function (index, person) {
    console.log(person, index);
    var postData = {filename: person};

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add-picture.php",
        data: postData,
        success:function(response){  
            var $li = $("<li>");
            var count = index + 1;
            // really you would set the text using something in `response`
            $li.text(postData.filename + " " + count + " of " + numPersons);
            $container.append($li);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgcgdmvh/2/)

Comment: it creates the images during page load and then I get internal error popup. No text on page.

Comment: Can you show how you changed your code to follow this stub?